# Running exe code from Matlab. The exact same instruction that works in cmd (dos) fails from Matlab

Tags: c++, c, windows, matlab, cmd

This is driving me crazy, I must admit. After finally being able to successfully compile two functions I need to process voice files, from C/C++ code that I downloaded from a trustworthy online repository (code that had been thoroughly tested in Linux), I am now struggling to launch those files from Matlab...

When I type the following command in cmd (dos)
Analysis b2.wav config_default
it works, no problem (see here [Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN0tD.jpg)).

Then, I build the exact same command into a string and feed it to the "system" Matlab function. Then the code crashes... (see here [Fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeRw6.jpg)) I've tried with full paths (c:\b2.wav, etc) but still does not work...

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Find the differences between the two processes: start by find the current directory and the `%PATH%` variable in both cases.

Comment: post the source code of analysis.exe, there is no way to know but guess without the code.

Comment: Hi @purplepsycho, I execute the m file from the same directory the executables are... Even if I only type system('Analysis b2.wav config_default') in Matlab's command window, it fails.

Comment: Hi @fluter, the Analysis.exe works from the dos command line. Is there, then, a need to know what it does or what the code is?

Comment: Have you tried the full path of the exe file? I wouldn't be surprised if Matlab would have their own executable with the same name....

Comment: we need to figure out what caused the program to crash, you could post the surrounding code of the crash line, not the entire program.

Comment: Hi @SimonKraemer. Good point. It fails, though

system('"C:\Users\JoseAntonio\Google Drive\Documents\Deusto\Voice\GlottHMM_RELEASE_v1.1\Analysis.exe" "C:\Users\JoseAntonio\Google Drive\Documents\Deusto\Voice\GlottHMM_RELEASE_v1.1\b2.wav" config_default')

Comment: @fluter how could I do that? If I try to debug the error, it just does not do anything else...

Comment: A folder name with a dot `.` on it "GlottHMM_RELEASE_v1.1" might be a problem in Windows systems. Avoid having folders with dots.

Comment: Sure @SembeiNorimaki. I also tried system('Analysis C:\b2.wav config_default') with no luck. I'll move both the exe and the wav to C: to fully test your suggestion... Same thing (edited after testing it)

Comment: Also the **\b** from "C:\b2.wav" might be interpreted as backspace string modifier. Try "C:\\b2.wav" (double backslash). PD: Yes, Windows is a pain.

Comment: Also correct me if I'm wrong, but you probably use Matlab because you want to run Analysis on several files, so you can use loops. Instead of executing analysis directly from Matlab, use Matlab to generate a .bat file with all the callings to Analysis (one in each line). Then just execute the .bat file from Terminal.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki
I copied the 3 files to c: and tried all these:
>> [status,cmdout] = system('Analysis b2.wav config_default');
>> [status,cmdout] = system('C:\Analysis C:\b2.wav C:\config_default');
>> [status,cmdout] = system('C:\\Analysis C:\\b2.wav C:\\config_default');
>> [status,cmdout] = system('C:\\Analysis.exe C:\\b2.wav C:\\config_default');
>> [status,cmdout] = system('Analysis.exe C:\\b2.wav config_default');

Nothing worked. I am probably missing something somewhere in between Matlab and DOS, since the program just works fine at either c: or the previous path in DOS

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am reusing C/C++ and Matlab codes that worked on Linux. I can actually split the Matlab code into parts than run on Matlab and generate inputs to the exes, then run the exes from cmd and go back to Matlab (I say exes since it is both Analysis.exe and Synthesis.exe that fail). But that is going to be quite a pain. Note I compiled them locally, so the exes I use are not the ones tested in Linux. But they do what they are supposed to by calling them from the cmd line...

Comment: Check my answer. You have to narrow down by discarding sources of errors. Maybe the parameters are not received correctly, maybe it's something wrong with your executable, maybe it's God conspirating against you... Just discard things until you find the error source.

Comment: True story @SembeiNorimaki, probably God. I'll read your answer now and try your suggestions step by step. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your image shows that the program Analysis stopped unexpectedly.

It might be a lot of reasons why, so let's go step by step:

1) Try executing Analysis from Terminal and passing wrong parameters (a file that doesn't exist, only one param (missing the config_defalut), no parameters at all, three parameters, etc...)

Can you make the program crash from terminal by passing wrong params?

2) Try creating the command first, checking that it's correct (\b is actually \b instead of a string modifier)

```
command_to_be_run = 'C:\Analysis C:\b2.wav C:\config_default'
disp(command_to_be_run)     % is it showing exacly what you want?
system(command_to_be_run);  % if so, run it.
```

3) Try creating a dummy executable dummy.exe in C that accepts two parameters and prints the received parameters (keep it super simple, just printing). Call it from Terminal. Does it work? Call it from Matlba. Does it Work?

With this 3 tests you can considerably narrow down where your error comes from.

By the way, is "config_default" a file or just a string that tells analysis how to behave? In some examples you treat it as a file, in others as a parameter without path.

Comment: 1) Analysis on its own has a description and usage indications (parameters needed etc). With a wrong file it says "cannot open file XYZ.wav". With a wrong config file (it is in fact a file) it says "Error reading" configuration file

Comment: 2) The series of instructions you posted work up to system again. That is actually how I have it in my Matlab code hehe, I just posted simplified stuff (to read) before

Comment: OK, so probably an issue with my exe files... They actually also crash when I try to run them from the Eclipse project (that's how I compiled them). I've made another simple exe that accepts 2 files, reads them and outputs the lines in the files. In this case, cmd and Matlab output the same thing

Comment: I've debugged the code(s) within Eclipse and they deliver: gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000135 at 0x7ff9394fcdd0, which I have read has to do with STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND. What amazes me is that running the code from cmd actually works...

Answer (score 1):

Based on what's been tried so far and the outputs, here's my theory:

- Premise: Analysis.exe came from code that's well tested in Linux. It works in Windows command line when run from the same directory where both it and the target file reside. But it stops working from Matlab console.
- Assertion 1: Matlab console does not operate within the context of the directory where the binary is but rather within the Matlab directory. As such, Analysis.exe will try to find the target from the Matlab directory.
- Validation for Assertion 1: Try putting the binary and the target wav in the Matlab directory. Then run system with the binary and target specified just by name (no path).
- Assertion 2: If the file's full path is specified to address this issue, it still doesn't work. This may be because the code assumed a Linux file system where the delimiter is "/" rather than "\".
- Validation for Assertion 2: Run with paths specified from the command line  while in a diferent directory to see if it fails or not.
- Possible Solution 1: Add the directory where both Analysis.exe and the target are into the Matlab path: (1) On the Home tab, in the Environment section, click Set Path. Add the path there. (2) addpath (folderName1,...,folderNameN) adds the specified folders to the top of the search path for the current MATLAB session. -> Then run the system command without the full paths.
- Possible Solution 2: Add the directory where both Analysis.exe and the target are into the Windows environment path. Then run the system command without the full paths.

EDIT: Possible hackish solution - Create a batch file where: (1) you would cd to the directory where Analysis.exe and the target wav are; and (2) do a Matlab system call to the batch file.

EDIT 2: Possible experiment to validate assertion 2.

Comment: Thanks @lynx0123. I may not have explained myself correctly but the C/C++ was compiled in Linux and worked from Matlab installed in Linux (have not done this myself). I have re-compiled the C/C++ code to generate new executables, so I guess there won't be issues with '\' vs '/'. Even if Matlab console works in the current directory (or based on Matlab's path), 'system' calls Window's cmd and I am in the same directory when running everything on Matlab as I am when running the exes from cmd...

Comment: I see. However, depending on how system call was implemented by Matlab, it might not operate within the context of the current directory (in fact, that's how most system calls are implemented). Anyway, to test this assertion, you can also try to add the directory where your binary and target wav are to the system environment path aside from the Matlab paths.

Comment: I think if there would be an issue with assertion 2 the program will not run from terminal. One question: Why Matlab? Try calling the executable from python for example and see if it also crashes.

Comment: It might if the current directory is where the command was invoked in which case path info is omitted. Anyway, thanks for your comment as it made me realize a possible experiment to validate assertion 2.